# react-native push-notification-ios geMessage and getAlert return undefined

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using react-native `0.62.2` and @react-native-community/push-notification-ios `1.4.0`. I recently upgraded from `0.61.5` and `1.0.3` respectively. Now, when I a user taps on a notification, the `getMessage` or the `getAlert` API returns undefined. The notification is displayed as expected on the phone. When I print the received notification, I see below:

```
{ _data: 
   { alarmId: '-MER20hCArS72IzmKDE1',
     uid: '-MBKyOBWjSzGtY-LPi4t'
   },
  _remoteNotificationCompleteCallbackCalled: false,
  _isRemote: undefined,
  _badgeCount: undefined,
  _sound: undefined,
  _alert: undefined,
  _title: undef2020-08-11 11:16:06.862887+0530 MyApp[1160:811760] SocketStream write error [0x280130fc0]: 1 32
ined,
  _category: 'i_am_up',
  _fireDate: undefined
}
```

`_alert` appears to be undefined in the above data but the notification is displayed correctly with the right alert message. In fact, not just the alert but other fields such as `fireDate`, `sound` are also undefined. I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Below is the call to schedule a notification

```
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
      fireDate: time,
      alertBody: alertBody,
      soundName: soundName,
      userInfo,
      category: category,
      repeatInterval: repeatInterval
})
```

P.S. I have also opened a github issue for this problem at https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios/issues/169 which also contains steps to reproduce using the example project in the repository.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Yes and it works great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue on my branch and create a pull request and finally have merged

https://github.com/nomi9995/push-notification-ios/tree/fix_169_issue

## Solution

now you simple install `1.4.1` by

```
yarn add @react-native-community/push-notification-ios
```